# Is this a correct code for finding even numbers in a list using recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I want to find the even numbers in a list using recursion, is the following a good code? (python)

```
def evenlis(lis):  
    n=len(lis)  
    if n==0:  
        return None  
    else:
        if lis[0]%2==0
            print lis[0]
        evenlis(lis[1:])
```

Comment: It has a syntax error, so doesn't even compile.

Comment: I take it that this is for some sort of practice? A real world application would *not* use recursion for this... It'll easily break on a long list...

Comment: Missing colon on the `if` in the `else`

Comment: *"Is this a correct code..."* why don't you **test it?!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are normally used to return values, after processing. In your case, you are printing the results. You can change that, like this

```
def evenlis(lis):  
    if len(lis) == 0:
        return []  
    else:
        return [lis[0]] if lis[0] % 2 == 0 else [] + evenlis(lis[1:])
```

1. If the length of the list is zero, return an empty list
2. Otherwise, use a conditional expression (`[lis[0]] if lis[0] % 2 == 0 else []`) to create a temporary list with the current element in it, if it is even
3. And concatenate it with the result of calling the same function recursively, with rest of the elements

But, as Jon mentioned in the comments, this will not scale for bigger lists, as we might consume all the stack space. We normally use a list comprehension, with the filtering condition to get the result, like this

```
even_list = [number for number in my_list if number % 2 == 0]
```

We iterate through the list, and check if the current number is divisible by 2 and if it does, we add that element to the resulting list.

Comment: I think that fourth eye gave you the ability to post pretty much this exact solution a few secs before I was going to :)

Comment: One can also avoid a modulus operation and bitwise it... `[number for number in my_list if not number & 1]` - less obvious what's happening,  but more efficient in the case of large integers